# Check session validity with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I start the application, I set a session variable. I'd like on each action (each controller action) check if this variable is still available or/and Session is null if it's the case redirect the action to /Account/LogOn

I tried using Application_BeginRequest but without success. I think there is a problem with the cycle (how is done first) Session_Start, Application_Start, ...

Do you have an idea how I can do ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Checking prerequest on Global.asx.cs may work.

```
    protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //Check session value  
    }
```

Comment: Trying to redirect from this to /Account/LogOn. I use the code gave by Darin Dimitrov http://goo.gl/5wfZ8 but the result is a page with a screen with the LogOn page and under the About page (I clicked on the About menu)